# Android Spinner : onItemSelected is never called

Tags: java, android, android-studio, triggers, spinner

I'm new to **Android Studio** and I'm encountering an annoying problem.

I created an Android application with a `Spinner` and an `EditView`. I want to display the selected item from the `Spinner`'s drop down list in the EditView but `public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` is **never triggered**. I used a `Log.d` to try to debug and saw that it never appears.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private EditText e;
    private Spinner spin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        e = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        spin = findViewById(R.id.spin);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cities);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "onItemSelected is called !"); // can't see it
                // normally here id do e.setText(spin.getSelectedItem().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: will the list be visible when you click on the spinner?

Comment: is the cities list not empty?

Comment: and when you select an item is what it becomes in the Spinner?

Comment: When I select an city in my Spinner, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and I noticed that if the cities list is filled before initializing the adapter  everything works correctly but if you fill the list of cities after initializing the adapter  in this case when I click on the spinner I see the list of cities but when I click I will have no change in the spiner or in the **setOnItemSelectedListener**
and I believe that's your problem please check if the list is filled before initializing the adapte and if this is not the case you must notify the adapter with the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();`

Comment: Yes! That's definitely it. As a fix, i added one fake city, but I don't know how can I fix it properly.

Comment: when your list is filled you need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged (); and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
if(adapter!=null){
            Log.d("DEBUG", "onItemSelected is called !"); // can't see it
            // normally here id do e.setText(spin.getSelectedItem().toString());
  }
        }
```

Comment: Try using  getActivity() instead of this keyword.

Comment: Use MainActivity.this then

Comment: One more thing:public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> cities;

Comment: Check my updated answer i think that was the actual problem.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to correct the mistake do check the answer now.

Comment: Is your log showing the message now or not.

Comment: Actually your ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<>(); is correct ,sorry for the mistake.Do change it back to ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Thanks, it builds well but same bug :)

Comment: Last one:  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { if(adapter!=null){
            Log.d("DEBUG", "onItemSelected is called !"); // can't see it
            // normally here id do e.setText(spin.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
        }

Answer (score -1):

Here my be this help

I recently used a spinner in my project here it is simple

```
 val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list_of_spinner)
            spSchedule.adapter = adapter

            spSchedule.onItemSelectedListener = object :
                AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

                    sedDual = list_of_spinner[position].toString()
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }
```

In the above code first, I add an adapter to the spinner as a drop-down view for the spinner

Here `spSchedule` is my spinner

Then on item click listener
I have stored the data in a string and there you will get the data

So if you want to show text selected from the spinner use this line

```
sedDual = list_of_spinner[position].toString()
```

Above code list_of_spinner [position] will give you the value you selected

Note this code is in kotlin